# Is every complete locally compact ring a DVR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, metric-spaces, local-rings

Recently, I have been trying to prove a theorem about all (non-field) domains $R$ complete and locally compact with respect to an absolute value $|\cdot|$. This begs first the question of classifying all such rings.

In the case that the absolute value is archimedean, we can proceed simply. The metric space completion $\overline{K}$ of the fraction field of $K$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by the Gelfand-Mazur theorem for Banach algebras. A computation shows that $R$ must be discrete, and there is a classification of discrete subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ saying that either $R=\mathbb{Z}$ or $R=\mathbb{Z}\left[(a+\sqrt{b^2+4a})/2\right]$ where $a$ is a negative integer and $|b|<2\sqrt{-a}$ is also an integer.

The case of non-archimedean absolute values is the one tripping me up. If $R$ were a DVR then life would be simple, since there is a well-known classification of complete DVRs. Can this be shown?

A sufficient answer to this question would also be giving a classification of complete fields, as was done in the archimedean case. It would be then left to me to try to piece together what complete subrings exist.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If $K$ is a complete, locally compact non-Archimedean field for an absolute value $|\cdot|$, then there is some nonzero $\pi \in K$ such that $D=\{x,\, |x| \leq |\pi|\}$ is compact. In particular, $B=\{x\, |x| < |\pi|\}$ is also compact so $|B|$ has a maximum $|\pi’| < |\pi|$. Then any real number between $|\pi’/\pi|$ and $1$ is not an absolute value, so $|\cdot|$ is discrete. Then $x \in D \longmapsto [x/\pi] \in k$ ($[\cdot]$ is projection to the residue field $k$) is continuous from a compact space onto a discrete one, so $k$ is finite. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Aphelli This comment seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I do have one point of confusion though. How are you able to initially assert that $B$ is compact?

Comment: It’s a non-Archimedean geometry fact. It follows from the fact that $D$ is compact and $B$ is closed – which is because the absolute value of any sequence converging to anything nonzero is stationary.